# Intel 8086: Why 4 memory segments

Tags: cpu-registers, x86-16, cpu-architecture

As far as I understand, the 8086 processor has 4 memory segments: Stack Segment, Code Segment, Data Segment and Extra Segment, with the corresponding segment registers (`SS`,`CS`,`DS`,`ES`)

The question is: "Why?"
Why not combine the Data and Code segments?
Why do we need the Extra Segment?
Why 4?

I know the question may sound dull, but I found this question in one of the 'Microprocessor Architectures' exams given last year at my college.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a couple more on 386+. But because of the segmented architecture _ES_ is very handy if you are doing a copy from one segment to another or need to temporarily access a segment outside of _DS_ (for instance video memory). If you combined CS and DS by default you'd be limited to CS=DS (and both being in the same 64kb segment). By splitting up CS and DS you can easily create a program where CS is in one 64kb segment and DS is in another. On 286+ these segments take on a different meaning in protected mode.

Comment: One instruction in particular `movs` (b/w/l) allows copying from one segment to another (or the same one). By default source is in DS:SI and destination address is in ES:DI.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's assume that we are on board with the decision to use a segmented architecture (the fact that there are segments in the first place). The "why" of that decision would be out of scope.

The more segment registers you have, the more complex the circuitry becomes, the more space it takes on the chip and the more expensive it gets; so you don't necessarily want to throw in dozens of them if they will go idle most of the time<sup>1</sup>. How many do you need?

You need one for the code, and that's CS.

You could use the same segment register for both code and data, but that severely hinders your ability to have more than 64kb of code + data. You can't temporarily "change CS" to access data on another part of the memory because CS is where your code is running. With only one register, no program would be able to access memory located more than 64kb away from the code (and realistically a lot less). You definitely need at least one data segment (DS)

Can you use one of those two for the stack? Yes, but again at a high cost. Using DS severely limits the program's ability to use more than 64kb of data. The stack segment is (usually) global to the program, so if it were located on the DS, you couldn't change DS without losing the stack, and you wouldn't be able to make CALLs until you got back to the "main" DS. Using the CS has a similar problem. You couldn't do FAR CALLs, that is having more than code segment, because they would break the stack. So, you need a dedicated SS. Note that you could also decide to fix the stack to be at a certain hardcoded memory location and you would not need an explicit SS. That's valid, and I believe some architectures did that, but you lose the flexibility to allocate a smaller stack when a large one would be wasteful, or even fancier techniques like using multiple stacks.

You could accomplish quite a lot with just those three. However, at some point you are going to have to copy or compare data between two segments, and you need a convenient way to do it that doesn't require loading one word to a general purpose register, changing segments, loading another word, changing segments back... Having an additional data segment makes code more compact and efficient. So we have ES, and that's our four segment registers.

More segment registers are possible and they would make more convenient to juggle more than two data segments at a time, but they are a luxury, no longer a necessity. Starting with the 80386, the x86 architecture did gain an extra pair of supplemental registers (FS and GS) that were intended to have the same uses as ES.

---

<sup>1</sup>Segment registers are not general purpose registers, so the usual RISC arguments don't necessarily apply; besides, RISC came well after the design of the x86 architecture.